# How to properly run nginx in docker swarm on MacOS?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-swarm

I have both compose & stack files with nginx service as

```
networks:
    custom_overlay_network:
        external: true

services:
   proxy:
        image: nginx:alpine
        ports:
            - target: 80
              published: 80
              protocol: tcp
              mode: host
        networks: 
            - custom_overlay_network
```

I also have tried a short ports variant:

```
ports:
    - "80:80"
```

here are networks settings nginx service in swarm (with/without `mode: host`)

```
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "c8d0dbff010c840f79d3e6c7ab7c0a225312ae6e28945e310a5f433f23baaadb",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "80/tcp": null
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/c8d0dbff010c",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "",
    ...
```

and here are setting nginx service in compose mode

```
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "22510ac75ac8e48f2c555d2bfc71ab47928ece59445b0db593eab882e26251e2",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "80/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "80"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/22510ac75ac8",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
```

when I run the service as compose - I have access to `http://localhost` content

but if I run service in swarm mode - I have no access to `http://localhost`

I also have no access to `http://<network IP address>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  custom_overlay_network:


services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    hostname: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - custom_overlay_network
```

Comment: i have used short ports variant - it does not help (

Comment: I guess the issue is with `mode: host`, if you remove it is should work in swarm too

Comment: if I remove `mode: host` how would I access service outside docker?